# How to retrive tag from a MPI_Irecv message?

Tags: c, mpi

I know that I can get the tag of an `MPI_Recv` message using `status.MPI_TAG` like so:

```
MPI_Recv(&buffer, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, globalComm, &status);
printf("The tag I received is %d\n",status.MPI_TAG);
```

Now, how do I get the tag of an `MPI_Irecv` message?

```
int buffer[2];
MPI_Request request;
MPI_Irecv(&buffer[0], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, globalComm, &request);
```

I tried using `request.MPI_TAG` but it did not work and gave me an error message instead.

Comment: It should be noted that `MPI_Request` is an opaque handle to which you have no direct access. That said, please never ask *it did not work / gave me an error* without including the specific error.

Answer (score 3):

the tag is only available when the message has been received,
so it might not be available when `MPI_Irecv()` returns.

The full sequence is

```
MPI_Irecv(&buffer[0], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, globalComm, &request);
// whatever you have to do
MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
// now the tag is in status.MPI_TAG
```

note there are other subroutines you can use in order to check a message has been received (prime examples are `MPI_Test()` and `MPI_Probe()`)

Comment: Hi, if I use MPI_Wait(&request, &status) it basically waits for a message to be received.  
If I had used the MPI_Irecv and MPI_Wait inside a loop, the code won't exit the loop until a message has been received. How do I prevent that?

Comment: take a deep breath and a step back. Unless you have a crystal ball, you cannot guess what the tag of the next message to be received will be. makes sense ? If at the end you think you need a crystal ball, something is wrong with your algo. Would `MPI_Irecv()` populating an array of requests and a single `MPI_Waitall()` outside the loop do the trick ?